# iPhone 11 - Leave lock screen after FaceId

Tags: iphone, touch-id, face-id

I just switched from iPhone 8 (touch id) to iPhone 11 (face id).

From the lock screen on iPhone 8, after touching the home button to do the finger print id, the phone would unlock and go to the home screen.

I've noticed with iPhone 11, the phone unlocks after face id, but remains on the lock screen, requiring me to swipe up from the bottom.

**Is there a way to automatically go to the home screen after face id?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer will be bit short because there's not much needed to provide an answer.

No.  It's designed to use Face ID to unlock the device only.

You still need to swipe up to open the device and get to the Home screen.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s meant to confirm that you actually want to unlock the phone.  A side effect of Face ID is that your phone will unlock during actions you’re taking while on the lock screen such as fast forwarding a song or quickly checking a new text message. Swiping up confirms you want to proceed past that basic functionality.